# The task is to build Java project in MVC model and I am not sure about its structure

Tags: java, model-view-controller

we got: one abstract superclass containing one method, and two subclasses redefining this method according to their needs. Not sure how to sructure project following MVC modeling.

Like, what exactly class model should have inside, controller and view?

Comment: What you are describing here is not enough for a MVC architecture. This is just one class hierarchy, which can either be part of the model, the controller or the view, but not all of them.

Answer (score 0):

In the most simple possible implementation:

- Your model class should do data access and no more; say for example that it should be the only one with an `import java.sql.whatever`, and return collections of beans fresh out from your repository.
- Your controller class should call your model layer, extract information and take a decision about what to show the user and how to do it.  For example: you can read a list of organization units and decide whether to send the user to a tree view of the units or, if there is only one unit, send them straight to an employee table with the people on that unit.  Spring MVC controllers or Struts 1/2 action classes are nice examples of this.  It should also leave the data available to the view in some accesible place (for example, as request attributes)
- Your view should be a JSP (or whatever view technology you use) as simple and with as few decisions taken in it as possible; all data is retrieved and navigation decisions are taken beforehand for it, and its only mission is to paint.